# What is the term for escapsulating content with something else?

Tags: obscure-terms

I am writing about a research journal article where they start and end the article with two separate anecdotal stories. I want to be able to say:

"Two lengthy anecdotes XXXXing the article are strangely out of place...."

It is the XXXX that I need.  So far the closest I have is 'escapsulate', but I think there is a better term for it out there - I just can't put my finger on it. "End-capping" was what came to mind immediately, but I did a quick google and that doesn't seem to mean what I thought it did.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try "bracketing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bookending**

> When you “bookend your speech”, you provide similar support for the
>   body of your speech. By opening and concluding your speech with a
>   common element, you neatly (and often artistically) provide cognitive
>   symmetry for the speech which you have delivered. You draw more
>   attention to your words, and give the impression that your message is
>   special and to be accepted.

(http://sixminutes.dlugan.com/bookending-speech-definition/)

Comment: I think that will work nicely. The 'bracketing' from @deadrat was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Two lengthy anecdotes constituting the article are strangely out of place....

Comment: The anecdotes are at the start and end, but there are another 15 pages of content in between, so constituting won't work sorry, as it implies the entire article is made of the two anecdotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the anecdotes would be ***[peripheral](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peripheral)***. Because then both the layout situation and lack of meaning are indicated.

> Definition of peripheral in English:
>   adjective
>
> 1 Relating to or situated on the edge or periphery of something:
>   the peripheral areas of Europe
>
> 1.1  Of secondary or minor importance; marginal:
>   she will see their problems as peripheral to her own

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peripheral

Comment: Nice suggestion! In this case I think peripheral could be used better later in the sentence, for example "Two lengthy anecdotes XXXXing the article are somewhat peripheral to the content...." - because it gives a good sense of the tangential nature of the anecdotes without coming across too negatively.

Comment: Glad it is useful. Tangential is kind of on spot as well.